# Laravel 5.2 method to check is view exists?

Tags: laravel, view

Is there any method to check if view exists?

Like PHP file_exists, but using internal laravel method for convenience

i want to code like this:

```
if(__ifViewExist__($view)){
    return view($view)->render();
}
return "Page tidak ditemukan";
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, an exists() method is available.

```
if(view()->exists($view)){
    return view($view)->render();
}
return "Page tidak ditemukan";
```

Comment: just for info -> you have @includeIf() directive added in Laravel 5.3

Comment: In case you want to check this in the blade files: https://webdevetc.com/programming-tricks/laravel/laravel-blade/how-to-check-if-a-blade-view-file-exists/

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Using the `View` facade.

```
// Return true when welcome.blade.php does not exist in theview folder
View::exists('welcome'); 

// Return false when login.blade.php does not exist in the view folder
View::exists('login');
```

Comment: @DzikriUlinnuhaA.Zamroni Maybe you need to escape with backslash \

Comment: @DzikriUlinnuhaA.Zamroni as long as it is in you aliases in your app/config.php providers, this is by default, you do use View;

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {    

      return view($view);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        return "Page tidak ditemukan";

    }
```

will be more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

In `web.php`, you need to type below given code:

```
Route::get('/Test',function(){
    if(View::exists('View'))
    {
        return view('View.php',['name' => 'Your string']);
    }
    return "File not found";
});
```

Comment: Instead of View.php just type the name of your View file e.g. Post.